# domain redirection with URL masking

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I am using a Clould Linux server with apache webserver. I need to enable the domain forwarding from "abcexam.in" to "xyzexam.com" with URL Masking. To achive this I am using a reverse proxy in abcexam.in Virtualhost like below.

[Screenshot of VirtualHost section with reverse proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEki2.png)

This method is perfectly working fine only for http:// websites not working for https:// (Not working when destination URL is https:// )

Is there any changes need to done in existing setup.